# Flask - Bootstrap in base.html

Tags: python, flask, flask-bootstrap

I want to add Bootstrap to my website. I have base.html and other files, which inherit from base.html, but in my base.html I want to have navbar, which will be displayed on every site. Unfortunately, after adding some bootstrap code, it''s no displayed, but if I add this code to index.html, it will be displayed.

My base.html:

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% block head %}
    {{ super() }}
    {% if title %}
    <title> {{ title }} - Book Blog</title>
    {% else %}
    <title> Welcome to Book Blog!</title>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{% block navbar %}
Microblog: 
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('show_books') }}">Books</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Login</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Logout</a>
    </li>
</ul>
{% endblock %}

<body>

<hr>
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
{% if messages %}
<ul>
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
{% endwith %}
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
```

So in this case the, the navbar isnt displayed. And as I wrote above, if I add nav classes to index.html, navbar displays only on this site. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The problem probably comes from your **index.html** page. In principle, your index page must inherit from the **base.html** template. What should give this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Welcome to Book Blog!{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div>
        <h1>Your content</h1>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Your template **base.html** can change slightly too:

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% block head %}
    {{ super() }}
    {% if title %}
        <title> {{ title }} - Book Blog</title>
    {% else %}
        <title> Welcome to Book Blog!</title>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<body>

{% block navbar %}
Microblog: 
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('show_books') }}">Books</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Login</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Logout</a>
    </li>
</ul>
{% endblock %}

    <hr>
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
        {% if messages %}
            <ul>
                {% for message in messages %}
                    <li>{{ message }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
           </ul>
       {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

I added a block tag to the body tag of your template. Now you should inherit this template in all pages where you want to have the same structure (navbar, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to import the Bootstrap Libs (Js, Css) on every page. I would recommend writing a `<title></title>` file you can import in every page. The same goes with the  attribute: Write a file for the Navbar and import it in the "Base Html" whenever you need the navbar.
Hopefully, I could help